# Using ‱ (per base point) character in strings

Tags: android, string, special-characters, android-resources

Any chance to use the ‱ (base point) in strings.xml? I paste the character but a ? appears. I can't find the HTML code.

Comment: The character “‱” is the PER TEN THOUSAND SIGN U+2031, denoting the number 0.0001 as a unit. It has limited [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2031/fontsupport.htm), which is probably the reason why you might see it as “?” in some programs.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML symbol is `&#8241;`

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunatelly I see no character in my TextView using &#8241; (it loads the text from resource file strings.xml)

Comment: Are you using `Html.fromhtml(yourString)`?

Comment: No just get the value with @string\resource_string_item

Comment: @Seraphim You need to use Html.fromHtml(R.string.resource_string_item) if you want to use HTML in your string. You'll have to pass that whole thing to setText() in the Java side

Comment: I'll try, but usually other html codes in string resource work well